# On a Archive: how could I break cache for the current year, but not the others?

Tags: cache

I have an archive of an event based site. 
I know how to break cache until the next event. No Problem

```
{% cache until nextEvent %}
```

But the archive works the following way:

archive
-- 2014 (latest year)
-- 2013
-- 2012
-- 2011

The until nextEvent part makes only sense for the latest year. The other years should be cached forever.

How could I achieve such a thing?

-- edit --

Maybe I have to go a little more into the details:
I get the year in the forth segment.
Now it should cache the whole loop and never break it, unless it's the actual year, then break it each night:

```
{% set latestYear = now|date("Y") %}

{% if year is not defined %}
    {% redirect "club/programm/archiv/"~latestYear %}
{% endif %}

{% set year = craft.request.getSegment(4) %}

{# Set the first day of the year and the last #}
{% set lastyear = year -1 %}
{% set nextyear = year +1 %}
{% set yearbegins = '1 January ' ~ year %}
{% set yearends = '1 January ' ~ nextyear %}
{% set unixbegins = yearbegins | date('U') %}
{% set unixends = yearends | date('U') %}

{# Today at 00:00 #}
{% set today = now|date("Y-m-d") ~ ' 00:00' %}
{% set tomorrow = now|date_modify("+1 day")|date("Y-m-d") ~ ' 00:00' %}

{% set entriesByYear = craft.entries.section('programm').limit(null).cf_date('and', '>= ' ~ unixbegins, '< ' ~ unixends, '< ' ~ today| date("U")) %} {# '> just to make syntax highlighting correct #}

{% cache until tomorrow %}
    {% for month, entries in entriesByYear | group("postDate|date('F')") %}

        {# MONTHLY HEADER #}
        <div class="program_monthly_header">
            <div class="content_column">
                <p>{{ month }} {{ year }} </p>
            </div>
        </div>

        {# ENTRIES PER MONTH #}
        {% for entry in entries %}

            <div class="listing_item{% if loop.last %} last{% endif %}" id="programm_{{ entry.slug }}"> 
                {% include "programm/_common" %}                    
            </div>
            <div class="clear"></div>
        {% endfor %}
    {% endfor %}
{% endcache %}
```

maybe that helps someone to help me ;)
cheers
stefan

--- edit 2 and solution ---

so after the comments of victor I updated the code. and it works like a charm:

```
{% set latestYear = now|date("Y") %}

{% if year is not defined %}
    {% redirect "club/programm/archiv/"~latestYear %}
{% endif %}

{% set year = craft.request.getSegment(4) %}

{# Set the first day of the year and the last #}
{% set lastyear = year -1 %}
{% set nextyear = year +1 %}
{% set yearbegins = '1 January ' ~ year %}
{% set yearends = '1 January ' ~ nextyear %}
{% set unixbegins = yearbegins | date('U') %}
{% set unixends = yearends | date('U') %}

{# Today at 00:00 #}
{% set today = now|date("Y-m-d") ~ ' 00:00' %}
{% set tomorrow = now|date_modify("+1 day")|date("Y-m-d") ~ ' 00:00' %}

{# Get the Date of the next Event, to allow caching until then #}
{% set nextEvent = craft.entries.section('programm').cf_date('>= ' ~ today| date("U")).order('cf_date asc').first() %}{# '> just to make syntax highlighting correct #}
{% set nextEventDate = nextEvent.cf_date|date_modify("+1 day")|date("Y-m-d") ~ ' 00:00' %}

{# Get all the events within the year concerned #}  
{% set entriesByYear = craft.entries.section('programm').limit(null).cf_date('and', '>= ' ~ unixbegins, '< ' ~ unixends, '< ' ~ today| date("U")) %} {# '> just to make syntax highlighting correct #}

{# If the year is the current year, cache it until the next event. Otherwhise, cache indefinitely #}
{% if year == latestYear %}
    {% cache until nextEventDate %}
        {% include "club/programm/_archive_common" %}
    {% endcache %}
{% else %}
    {% cache %}
        {% include "club/programm/_archive_common" %}
    {% endcache %}
{% endif %}
```

thanks for all the fish!
stefan

Answer (score 1):

You could use the new [Cold Cache pluging from P&T](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ColdCache/) which:

> Adds a new `{% coldcache %}` tag to Craft, which works just like Craft’s
>   built-in `{% cache %}` tag, except that this tag won’t record which
>   elements and element queries are active between its tags. The only way
>   caches will ever get deleted is if they expire, or an admin clears
>   them using the Clear Caches tool in Settings.

Comment: I know that coldcache exists, but that doesn't solve the problem, or does it?

Comment: I don't know how your template looks, but I would create two for-loops: One for the current year (and wrap it in `{% cache until nextEvent %}`) and one for everything else (`{% coldcache %}`).

Comment: just after posting my remark, I understood what you meant... I've updated the question as well. Two loops would be an option - you are completely right... I wish there was a way with only one loop, but I guess it's OK like you proposed... btw: don't really need coldcache, I just don't want to break it every night... cheers

Comment: @outline4 Now I understand that you have a separate page for each year. Why don't you just use `{% cache %}`? It will be saved for each page separately and only cleared when an entry matching that query gets updated.

Comment: no, since it's event based, the events are only going into the archive after a certain date, not when they are edited! that's what it's all about... I will update the question with the answer. that I actually found because of your initial comment ;)

Comment: @outline4 Glad you got it sorted ;)